# how to modify stop word list in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am quite new to elastic search, we are trying to incorporate new search engine(Elastic search) in our project.
But we have specific stop words list maintained for project.

Is there any stop words file is maintained in elastic search ? Where it is located ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Stop Words Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-analyzer.html) and  [Stop Words Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html).
These docs define how you would use your own stopwords in ES.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can write your custom analyzer for specific stop words if you want to introduce or you can use in-build analyzer which meets your requirement.
    please refer below link to add stop words manually in custom analyzer.

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html

PUT /my_index/testsachin
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": { 
          "type": "standard", 
          "stopwords": [ "and", "the" ] 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

please check if its helpful